# Disregard duplicate rows only when these rows are contiguous

Tags: sql, hana

I am trying to show only the first occurrence of an activity if this activity occurs multiple times in a row.

Thus, in the scenario below, if activity `B` occurs 3 times in a row, even if it is at different times, I want to only select the first occurrence. If it occurs again AFTER another activity I also want to keep that.

**I want to disregard rows 3 & 4**

| ROW | CASEKEY | ACTIVITY | EVENTTIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 01.01.2021 12:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | B | 01.01.2021 12:05:00 |
| 3 | 1 | B | 01.01.2021 12:06:00 |
| 4 | 1 | B | 02.01.2021 13:00:00 |
| 5 | 1 | C | 02.01.2021 13:10:00 |
| 6 | 1 | B | 03.01.2021 12:00:00 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(activity) over (partition by casekey order by eventtime) as prev_activity
      from t
     ) t
where prev_activity is null or prev_activity <> activity;
```